How to check that all entries of a timestamp column in dataframe has UTC timezone?
I have a dataframe with a timestamp column. I want to assert that all entries for this column have UTC time stamp.
I tried
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame with a deal_timestamp column
data = {
    'ts': [
        pd.Timestamp('2024-06-11 12:00:00', tz='UTC'),
        pd.Timestamp('2024-06-11 13:00:00', tz='UTC'),
        pd.Timestamp('2024-06-11 14:00:00', tz='US/Pacific')
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

all_utc = df['ts'].dt.tz == 'UTC'
assert all(all_utc), f"Some timestamps are not in UTC: {df[~all_utc]}"

but I get the error

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

I know there are some non-vectorized ways to do this, but I feel there should be a vectorized way to do what I need.

The issue is that you have an object Series, therefore there is no dt.tz accessor:
df['ts'].dtype
# dtype('O')

You can convert to_datetime, but this will lose the original timezone since there can only be one timezone in a datetime Series:
pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], utc=True)

0   2024-06-11 12:00:00+00:00
1   2024-06-11 13:00:00+00:00
2   2024-06-11 21:00:00+00:00
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]  # <- only one timezone

pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], utc=True).dt.tz
# datetime.timezone.utc

Another option would be to use map:
all_utc = df['ts'].map(lambda t: t.tz).astype(str) == 'UTC'

0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: ts, dtype: bool

Then:
assert all(all_utc), f"Some timestamps are not in UTC: {', '.join(df.loc[~all_utc, 'ts'].astype(str))}"

# AssertionError: Some timestamps are not in UTC: 2024-06-11 14:00:00-07:00

